# React js redirect with authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new with Reactjs and I've seen some questions about redirect/authentication routes if user is logged in or not.

I'm trying to create an authentication file that checks if received token matches and return `true` or `false` according to that.

I'm able to execute the function but on `routes.js` file I'm getting a pending promise even if I use `async/await`. I want `IsAuthenticated` returns true or false.

[image: console]

auth.js:

```
const auth = {

    isAuth: false,
    authing: (async () => {
            
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    
        await axios.post('http://localhost/api/login/auth.php', { "token": token }).then(res => {
    
            console.log(res.data);
                
            if (res.data === "authorized") {
                
                auth.isAuth = true; 
            }
    
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Access denied');
        });
        console.log(auth.isAuth)
        return auth.isAuth;
    })()
}

export const IsAuthenticated = () => auth.authing;
```

routes.js:

```
import { IsAuthenticated } from './auth';

console.log(IsAuthenticated()); // console.log a promise

export default function Routes() {
    
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={props =>
                    IsAuthenticated() ? (
                        <Component {...props} />
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
                    )
                }
            />
        )
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/Home" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, I believe that when you export as "() => " this already called auth.authing

when you call console.log with IsAuthenticated() this was, as logged, already fulfilled.

I would try either trying to console just "IsAuthenticated" or exporting "auth.authing" then loggin "IsAuthenticated()"

---

EDIT:
Using quokka for a quick playground, I found out that you're indeed returning a promise... auth.authing is a promise itself.

basically, the solution is to "await IsAuthenticated()"

here's the code:

```js
const auth = {

  isAuth: false,
  authing: (async () => {

    await Promise.resolve({data:"authorized"}).then(res => {

      console.log(res.data);

      if (res.data === "authorized") {

        auth.isAuth = true;
      }

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('Access denied');
    });
    console.log(auth.isAuth);
    return auth.isAuth;
  })()
};

const IsAuthenticated = () => auth.authing;

console.log(await IsAuthenticated())
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Still getting a promise exporting `auth.authing` and console.log just "IsAuthenticated".

Comment: @madsongr I've edited my response, you have to await IsAuthenticated

Comment: Still not working. `console.log(await IsAuthenticated())` is displaying an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
const auth =  async()=>{
        try { // simplify code with trycatch
            const {data} = await axios.post('http://localhost/api/login/auth.php', { "token": token })
            if (data === "authorized") {
             // we know him
             return true;
            }else{
             // stranger alert!!
             return false;

            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Something went wrong');
            console.log(error);
            return false;  
        }
    }


exports const IsAuthenticated = auth();
```

It seems you're doing too much, return true or false from your auth() function. something like so then save as a variable "IsAuthenticated" to use without bracket in your case like so

```
export default function Routes() {

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                IsAuthenticated ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} 
/>
                )
            }
        />
    )
}

return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/Home" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time. Still not working. I get the same result (a promise) on console.log(IsAuthenticated) in routes.js. And it was giving me an error with `exports const IsAuthenticated = auth(); `. Had to change it to `export const IsAuthenticated = auth(); `